# Is there an extensive XYZ Cube diagnosis resource?

Tags: print-quality

I love the idea of the XYZ test cube to help diagnose my bad prints.   I’m able to find online very common print issues however am looking for a resource that is more extensive. Often I run into a situation where my issue is not covered.

Would be great if there was a resource that had pictures of numerous bad or less than ideal XYZ prints with cause and fix for each. I’m thinking of more than 50 examples.

Does anyone know of such a resource?

[image: My current unknown bad XYZ print]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An XYZ cube is a calibration test for dimensional accuracy testing, it is not meant for extensive trouble shooting. Therefor, there are no specific resources for cube irregularities, the regular resources can be used for trouble shooting.

One of the better resources for troubleshooting print problems is found at [Simplify3D](https://www.simplify3d.com/support/print-quality-troubleshooting/) or one at [All3DP](https://all3dp.com/1/common-3d-printing-problems-troubleshooting-3d-printer-issues/).

---

*Do note that the dimensions in X and Y and Z are based on mechanical ratio's of the steppers with their pulleys or threaded rods, you can calculate the amount of steps required for the dimensional accuracy. It is only necessary to adjust this if e.g. the pulley is of a different diameter than the specification (as in poor quality dimensional pulley accuracy). In the basis you should not adjust the steps per mm based on small sized calibration cubes.*

Comment: What type of test would you recommend for extensive testing ?

Comment: @wallwalker What kind of printer is this? E.g. did you check the belt tension, it appears you have positioning problems. The initial distance also might be a bit too large, but it is difficult to see. On Thingiverse there are many calibration tests to be found.

Answer (score 1):

One of the sites that I have gone to for identifying problems is All3DP.com's page "[3D Printing Troubleshooting All Common Problems](https://all3dp.com/1/common-3d-printing-problems-troubleshooting-3d-printer-issues/)". Here are the FDM and SLA issues they cover:

### FDM 3D Printing Problems

**Nothing is Printing**

- [Out of Filament](https://all3dp.com/1/common-3d-printing-problems-troubleshooting-3d-printer-issues/#out-of-filament)
- [Nozzle Too Close to Print Bed](https://all3dp.com/1/common-3d-printing-problems-troubleshooting-3d-printer-issues/#nozzle-too-close-to-print-bed)
- [Blocked Nozzle](https://all3dp.com/1/common-3d-printing-problems-troubleshooting-3d-printer-issues/#blocked-nozzle)
- [Print Head Misses the Bed](https://all3dp.com/1/common-3d-printing-problems-troubleshooting-3d-printer-issues/#print-head-misses-the-bed)
- [Snapped Filament](https://all3dp.com/1/common-3d-printing-problems-troubleshooting-3d-printer-issues/#snapped-filament)
- [Stripped Filament](https://all3dp.com/1/common-3d-printing-problems-troubleshooting-3d-printer-issues/#stripped-filament)

**My Print Failed**

- [Extrusion Stopped Mid-Print](https://all3dp.com/1/common-3d-printing-problems-troubleshooting-3d-printer-issues/#extrusion-stopped-mid-print)
- [Print Doesn't Stick to Print Bed](https://all3dp.com/1/common-3d-printing-problems-troubleshooting-3d-printer-issues/#print-doesnt-stick-to-print-bed)
- [Supports Fell Apart](https://all3dp.com/1/common-3d-printing-problems-troubleshooting-3d-printer-issues/#supports-fell-apart)

**My Print Looks Bad**

- [First Layer is Messy](https://all3dp.com/1/common-3d-printing-problems-troubleshooting-3d-printer-issues/#first-layer-is-messy)
- [Print Bows Out at Bottom (Elephant's Foot)](https://all3dp.com/1/common-3d-printing-problems-troubleshooting-3d-printer-issues/#print-bows-out-at-bottom-elephants-foot)
- [Print Edges are Bending (Warping)](https://all3dp.com/1/common-3d-printing-problems-troubleshooting-3d-printer-issues/#print-edges-are-bending-warping)
- [Infill Looks Messy and Incomplete](https://all3dp.com/1/common-3d-printing-problems-troubleshooting-3d-printer-issues/#infill-looks-messy-and-incomplete)
- [Gaps Between Infill and Outer Wall](https://all3dp.com/1/common-3d-printing-problems-troubleshooting-3d-printer-issues/#gaps-between-infill-and-outer-wall)
- [Infill is Visible from the Outside](https://all3dp.com/1/common-3d-printing-problems-troubleshooting-3d-printer-issues/#infill-is-visible-from-the-outside)
- [Cracks Have Appeared in Tall Objects](https://all3dp.com/1/common-3d-printing-problems-troubleshooting-3d-printer-issues/#cracks-have-appeared-in-tall-objects)
- [Layers Don't Line Up Well](https://all3dp.com/1/common-3d-printing-problems-troubleshooting-3d-printer-issues/#layers-dont-line-up-well)
- [Some Layers are Missing](https://all3dp.com/1/common-3d-printing-problems-troubleshooting-3d-printer-issues/#some-layers-are-missing)
- [Print Leans When it Shouldn't](https://all3dp.com/1/common-3d-printing-problems-troubleshooting-3d-printer-issues/#print-leans-when-it-shouldnt)
- [Overhangs are Messy](https://all3dp.com/1/common-3d-printing-problems-troubleshooting-3d-printer-issues/#overhangs-are-messy)
- [Surface Areas Beneath Supports are Rough](https://all3dp.com/1/common-3d-printing-problems-troubleshooting-3d-printer-issues/#surface-areas-beneath-supports-are-rough)
- [Print is Unusually Weak/Looks Wrong (Non-Manifold Edges)](https://all3dp.com/1/common-3d-printing-problems-troubleshooting-3d-printer-issues/#print-is-unusually-weak-looks-wrong-non-manifold-edges)
- [Fine Detail Not Printing Correctly](https://all3dp.com/1/common-3d-printing-problems-troubleshooting-3d-printer-issues/#fine-detail-not-printing-correctly)
- [Ripples and "Echoes" in Print (Ringing)](https://all3dp.com/1/common-3d-printing-problems-troubleshooting-3d-printer-issues/#ripples-and-echoes-in-print-ringing)
- [Diagonal Scars on Print](https://all3dp.com/1/common-3d-printing-problems-troubleshooting-3d-printer-issues/#diagonal-scars-on-print)
- [Print Looks Stringy and Droopy (Over-Extrusion)](https://all3dp.com/1/common-3d-printing-problems-troubleshooting-3d-printer-issues/#print-looks-stringy-and-droopy-over-extrusion)
- [Print Layers Look Uniformly Thin/Weak (Under-Extrusion)](https://all3dp.com/1/common-3d-printing-problems-troubleshooting-3d-printer-issues/#print-layers-look-uniformly-thin-weak-under-extrusion)
- [Print Looks Melted and Deformed](https://all3dp.com/1/common-3d-printing-problems-troubleshooting-3d-printer-issues/#print-looks-melted-and-deformed)
- [Pits and Hollows in Top Layer (Pillowing)](https://all3dp.com/1/common-3d-printing-problems-troubleshooting-3d-printer-issues/#pits-and-hollows-in-top-layer-pillowing)
- [Web-like Strings Cover the Print (Stringing)](https://all3dp.com/1/common-3d-printing-problems-troubleshooting-3d-printer-issues/#web-like-strings-cover-the-print-stringing)
- [Print Has Lost Dimensional Accuracy](https://all3dp.com/1/common-3d-printing-problems-troubleshooting-3d-printer-issues/#print-has-lost-dimensional-accuracy)
- [Print Offset in Some Places](https://all3dp.com/1/common-3d-printing-problems-troubleshooting-3d-printer-issues/#print-offset-in-some-places)
- [Bridges are Messy](https://all3dp.com/1/common-3d-printing-problems-troubleshooting-3d-printer-issues/#bridges-are-messy)

**Something Else**

- [Print is Stuck to Print Bed](https://all3dp.com/1/common-3d-printing-problems-troubleshooting-3d-printer-issues/#print-is-stuck-to-print-bed)

---

### SLA 3D Printing Problems

**Nothing is Printing**

- [Resin too Cold](https://all3dp.com/1/common-3d-printing-problems-troubleshooting-3d-printer-issues/#resin-too-cold)
- [Printing too Fast](https://all3dp.com/1/common-3d-printing-problems-troubleshooting-3d-printer-issues/#printing-too-fast)
- [Underpowered Laser](https://all3dp.com/1/common-3d-printing-problems-troubleshooting-3d-printer-issues/#underpowered-laser)

**My Print Failed**

- [Prints Not Adhering to Print Plate](https://all3dp.com/1/common-3d-printing-problems-troubleshooting-3d-printer-issues/#prints-not-adhering-to-print-plate)
- [A Section of the Print/Supports Detached or Moved](https://all3dp.com/1/common-3d-printing-problems-troubleshooting-3d-printer-issues/#a-section-of-the-print-supports-detached-or-moved)

**My Print Looks Bad**

- [Layers Have Separated (Delamination)](https://all3dp.com/1/common-3d-printing-problems-troubleshooting-3d-printer-issues/#layers-have-separated-delamination)
- [Small Fins and Disks Attached to Print (Ragging)](https://all3dp.com/1/common-3d-printing-problems-troubleshooting-3d-printer-issues/#small-fins-and-disks-attached-to-print-ragging)